# Проект с использованием Swing

Tags: проектирование, java, swing

Когда садишься писать первый раз более менее серьезный проект возникает этот вопрос. Как грамотно разделить логику программы и графический интерфейс? Объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах. Допустим есть основной класс Main, который я хочу наследовать от JFrame, но не хочу сильно "загрязнять" конструктор. Поэтому создаю второй класс CreateGUI, чтобы потом просто красиво в конструктор Main'a добавить методы. Это нормально?. Как лучше работать с этими двумя классами? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ммм... не знаю как другие, а я вообще ничего не понял из описания. Лучше добавьте примеры кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если вообще все делать по красоте =) можно и с MVC ознакомится =)
[[@nk32](/users/5589/nk32)](/users/5589/nk32), я бы не обобщал весь ГУИ и `extends JFrame`, обычно `JFrame` может содержать только вид главного окна.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно весь GUI просто выносят в отдельный класс примерно так. Если есть, например, большое меню, можно сделать отдельный класс для меню. Работайте не с методами, а с объектами.

```
 public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {       
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        new GUI();
                }
            });    
        }       
    }

    public class GUI extends JFrame {

        public GUI() {
              // .....    
        }
    }
```